# MediaRecorder, getMaxAmplitude always returns 0

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I have developed this small MediaRecorder application. I have 3 buttons- `Play` (for Start Recording), `Pause` (for stop recording), `Max` (for finding Max Amplitude). I Googled to get it correct, but nothing worked fine for me.

The problem is it always give me 0 for `getMaxAmplitude`.

Below is the code i am using. Can any one please help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button play,pause, max;

    String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
          getAbsolutePath() + "/myexampl.3gp";
    MediaRecorder mrecorder=new MediaRecorder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pause= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        max = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        mrecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mrecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    mrecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mrecorder.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starts Recording!", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    mrecorder.stop();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mrecorder.release();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stops Recording!", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        max.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            int ampl=0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                ampl=mrecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(ampl), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: It always will the first time.  Did you hit it multiple times?  Also, were you recording between the first and second times you hit it?  If not, there were no samples so the amplitude of no samples is 0.

Comment: Hi, What I am doing is, I'm pressing the 'Play' button, recording something for 4-5 seconds, later I press the 'Max' button, but it always return 0.

Comment: It always will the first time.  Does it do so the second time?  And is the recording actually working?

Comment: I guess recording is working, because I added one more button and added MediaPlayer functionality to check my recording, and it's working fine.

Comment: Though 'Max' button always gives me 0 value

Comment: _"later I press the 'Max' button"_. You're pressing the Max button after you've stopped recording? That's not going to work. The measurements are only updated while you're recording, and the measuring doesn't start until you've called `getMaxAmplitude` once. So if your first call to `getMaxAmplitude` comes after you've stopped recording you're just going to get the initial value of 0 every time.

Comment: No, I am pressing 'Max' button before pressing 'Stop'.